# Find date Difference between rows based on first row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have a QC check dates that will contain a id, event and date of event. below is the data for reference.

```
 QUALITY_CHECK_NO   EVENT                   DATE
 101                QC EVENT 1              2015-01-07 00:00:00
 101                QC EVENT 2              2015-08-10 00:00:00
 101                QC EVENT 3              2015-08-13 00:00:00
 101                QC EVENT 4              2015-08-25 00:00:00
 101                QC EVENT 5              2015-08-11 00:00:00
 101                QC EVENT 6              2015-08-13 00:00:00
 101                QC EVENT 7              2015-08-18 00:00:00
 101                QC EVENT 8              2015-08-19 00:00:00
 101                QC EVENT 9              2015-08-24 00:00:00
 101                QC EVENT 10             2015-08-25 00:00:00
 101                QC EVENT 11             2015-08-25 00:00:00
 101                QC EVENT 12             2015-09-11 00:00:00
 101                QC EVENT 13             2015-09-25 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 1              2015-01-07 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 2              2015-08-10 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 3              2015-08-26 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 4              2015-08-27 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 5              2015-08-21 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 6              2015-08-20 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 7              2015-08-26 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 8              2015-08-26 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 9              2015-08-27 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 10             2015-08-27 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 11             2015-08-27 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 12             2015-09-11 00:00:00
 102                QC EVENT 13             2015-09-25 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 1              2015-01-07 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 2              2015-08-10 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 3              2015-08-12 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 4              2015-08-25 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 5              2015-08-21 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 6              2015-08-11 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 7              2015-08-20 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 8              2015-08-20 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 9              2015-08-24 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 10             2015-08-25 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 11             2015-08-25 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 12             2015-09-11 00:00:00
 103                QC EVENT 13             2015-09-25 00:00:00
 104                QC EVENT 1              2015-10-20 00:00:00
 104                QC EVENT 2              2015-10-21 00:00:00
 104                QC EVENT 3              2015-10-21 00:00:00
 104                QC EVENT 4              2015-10-23 00:00:00
```

I want to find the days difference between the first event date and the next rows for each QualityCheckNo. I tried using a CTE however i'm getting the days difference between each rows and not what I am looking for.

Basically I need to find how much days difference has been there from QC Event 1 and EVENTS. Something like below..

```
 QUALITY_CHECK_NO   EVENT       DATE                  DaysDiff
 101                QC EVENT 1  2015-01-07 00:00:00    0
 101                QC EVENT 2  2015-08-10 00:00:00    215
 101                QC EVENT 3  2015-08-13 00:00:00    218
 101                QC EVENT 4  2015-08-25 00:00:00    230
 101                QC EVENT 5  2015-08-11 00:00:00    216
 101                QC EVENT 6  2015-08-13 00:00:00    218
```

Below is the sql code that i used.

```
WITH tableNumbered AS (
        SELECT QUALITY_CHECK_NO, EVENT, DATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SiteID ORDER BY SITEID, RNUM) as rNum FROM [db_lexitas_ods].[dbo].[vw_GetPvtDocumentTAT] )
        SELECT t.*,
           DATEDIFF(day,t2.[DATE],t.[DATE])
      as Daysdiff
    FROM tableNumbered t
    LEFT JOIN tableNumbered t2 ON t.[QUALITY_CHECK_NO] = t2.[QUALITY_CHECK_NO] AND t2.rNum + 1 = t.rNum
```

Comment: What is your db/version

Comment: Assuming SQL Server due to the [brackets]. Your sample SQL does not match the sample data. How am I supposed to run it? Make up the schema myself? Please make it easy for us if you want help.

Comment: Hi, The code has been updated and the code is finding the difference in days from previous row and current row. How ever i want to find the days difference based on first row and other rows.

Comment: @KarthikVenkatraman - can you use http://sqlfiddle.com and recreate the table with data and then share the link in question? Would be lot easier for us to play around like that

Answer (score 3):

```
select
    datediff(
        dd,
        min(EVENTDATE) over (partition by QUALITY_CHECK_NO),
        EVENTDATE
    )
from T
```

This assumes that Event 1 is always the earliest date. The `min` expression could also be replaced by this to do a lookup by event name:

```
(
    select EVENTDATE from T t2
    where
            t2.QUALITY_CHECK_NO = t.QUALITY_CHECK_NO
        and EVENT = 'QC EVENT 1'
),
```

Your attempt nearly worked except that the join condition needs to be on rNum equal to 1 instead of rNum + 1. And since you want zero for the first difference a regular inner join works as well.

There is another posted answer that uses a `group by` and `join` to accomplish the same thing and the query plans are probably going to be the same as the correlated subquery in the second option above. Using a scalar subquery might have an advantage because it will throw an error if it were written wrong and returned more than one row.

Comment: How this code will get me the date difference between first row of a QualityCheckNo and the other consecutive rows..

Comment: The starting date in your calculation is easy to look up since it has a fixed/known description and is also apparently the earliest date in the group. So use those facts to your advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should be able to solve your requirement.

```
Select QUALITY_CHECK_NO, EVENT, DATE, datediff(day, (select top(1) DATE from <table_name>), DATE) as DaysDiff from <table_name>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    tableNumbered.Quality_Check_No
    ,tableNumbered.Event
    ,[tableNumbered.Date] [Date]
    ,DATEDIFF(d,Grp.MinDate,[tableNumbered.Date]) AS DateDiff
FROM 
     tableNumbered 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT Quality_Check_No, MIN(CONVERT(date,[Date]) AS MinDate)
     FROM tableNumbered 
     GROUP BY Quality_Check_No
    ) Grp ON tableNumbered.Quality_Check_No = Grp.Quality_Check_No
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only purpose is to finding the days difference between previous row then your can use LAG().

```
SELECT QUALITY_CHECK_NO,EVENT,date,
DATEDIFF(day,LAG(DATE) OVER (ORDER BY EVENT),DATE)
FROM Table
```

The detailed explanation for LEAD() and LAG() can be found [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/25/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement-part-4/).

The working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43c43/10) for same.